# Shopify: Oauth error missing_shopify_permission

Tags: oauth, shopify, admin

Somehow I am getting
[image: shopify oauth error]
above error when I login into Shopify admin, any clue what is wrong?

Comment: Same here. I have an Australian based store. I think I have the plug-in for local-pickup enabled (the shopify made one ) but other than that no custom plugins.

Comment: Try deleting all the cookies and then login again.